# Rank of infinite family of elliptic curves over the rationals without assuming finiteness of Sha

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, tate-shafarevich-groups

Are there any known infinite families of elliptic curves over the rationals, that are proved to have rank $\geq 2$, without assuming finiteness of their Tate-Shafarevich group?

Comment: Sure, take an elliptic surface whose rank over the base is $2$. Then by Silverman's specialisation theorem, all but finitely many fibres have rank at least $2$. As far as I know the open question is to have infinitely many elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose rank is **exactly** 2

Comment: Thank you! Yes, what I really had in mind is the open question! So there is no known infinite family of elliptic curves of rank exactly two over the rationals.